# Reading html file via vba

Tags: vba

In my project, I'm reading a html file with vba codes and I'm scannig it with some substrings then I'm creating a json file with these substrings. **SUBTASK** is one of my substrings. When I'm scanning the html file, it's finding 9 **SUBTASK** but in my html file there are more than 9. My codes like this.

```
            For i = 1 To lastrow                    
                txt = Cells(i, 1)                    
                If txt = "All" Or txt = "ALL" Or txt = "V2500-A5" Then   'Or txt = "V2500-A1"
                    engType = txt
                End If

                If txt = "About" Then GoTo skipNextRow

                If Left(txt, 1) <> "0" And Left(txt, 5) <> "TASK " And Left(txt, 4) <> "DMC:" And Right(Left(txt, 11), 8) <> "SUBTASK " Then GoTo skipNextRow                                                            

                If Left(txt, 5) = "TASK " Then
                    locationTASK = InStr(1, txt, "TASK ")

                ElseIf Left(txt, 4) = "DMC:" Then
                    locationDMC = InStr(1, txt, "DMC:")
                    locationIssueNo = InStr(1, txt, "Issue No:")
                    locationIssueDate = InStr(1, txt, "Issue Date:")

                ElseIf Right(Left(txt, 11), 8) = "SUBTASK " Then

                    Debug.Print "Subtask: " & txt
                    locationSUBTASK = InStr(1, txt, "SUBTASK ")

                End If                    

skipNextRow:

           Next i

           ReDim Preserve arrApplicability(w): arrApplicability(w) = engType
           ReDim Preserve arrPartNo(w): arrPartNo(w) = myTemp
           w = w + 1
```

My issue in **SUBTASK** section, there are no issue in other sections.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you narrow it down to a more manageable question?

Comment: @braX I edited my codes. There are only reading and scanning codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are finding text is a bit shaky. There isn't much room for changes in the expected format. Without seeing your actual input, it will be a lot of guesswork, but here it goes.
I suspect that the word subtask is placed in different columns and you are only getting those that start in column 4. Here are a few tips that might make your debugging easier.

1. This will help you find the missed rows and where they are. Replace the `End If` with

```
    Else
        locationSUBTASK = InStr(1, txt, "SUBTASK")
        Debug.Print "SUBTASK found in position " & locationSUBTASK 
    End If
```

2. `Mid` is a function that will help you a bit. Replace `Right(Left(txt, 11), 8)` with `Mid(txt, 4, 8)`. Doesn't really help your current issue, but still.
3. Learn about regular expressions. Here is a snippet that will help you get started:

```
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Matches As Object

    Dim txt As String
    txt = "something SUBTASK yada yada"

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    RegExp.Pattern = ".*SUBTASK (.*)"
    Set Matches = RegExp.Execute(txt)
    Debug.Print Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
```

The pattern `".*SUBTASK (.*)"` means "Find the word 'SUBTASK ' anywhere in a line and keep track of what's coming after it.". The `(.*)` part will be recognized as a submatch.

Comment: Yup. Use Regular Expressions. Instead of generic objects, I prefer to use                    Dim regex As RegExp, matches As MatchCollection, sm As SubMatches

Comment: @TomRobinson, I agree. In this case I opted for generic objects to lower the entrance threshold. Not sure if that is good or bad.